# Which "linear estimators" are actually permitted in the Gauss Markov Theorem?

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression

Let $y$ be an $n\times 1$ vector and $X$ be a $n\times k$ matrix. Suppose that (i) $y=X\beta+\varepsilon$ where $E[\varepsilon|X]=0$, (ii) $X'X$ has rank $k$, and (iii) $E[\varepsilon\varepsilon'|X]=\sigma^{2}(X'X)^{-1}$.

The famous Gauss-Markov (GM) Theorem says that, under the assumptions above, the OLS estimator $\hat{\beta} = (X'X)^{-1}X'y$ is the minimum variance linear unbiased estimator of $\beta$ in the linear regression equation $y = X\beta +\varepsilon$.

Check out the wikipedia proof [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20statistics%2C%20the%20Gauss%E2%80%93Markov,and%20expectation%20value%20of%20zero.) (note that wikipedia assumes $X$ is non-stochastic).

Looking through a variety of textbooks, when the Theorem says that $\hat{\beta}$ is the minimum variance **linear** unbiased estimator, it seems it means it is the minimum variance unbiased estimator out of all estimators that can be written as $Cy$ for some $k\times n$ matrix $C$.

**However, every proof I have seen seems to implicitly assume that $E[C|X]=C$.**

To plead my case, take the wikipedia example ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20statistics%2C%20the%20Gauss%E2%80%93Markov,and%20expectation%20value%20of%20zero.)).

Wikipedia assumes that $X$ is non-stochastic, but I will accomplish this by conditioning on $X$.

If $\hat{\gamma}=Cy$, then defining $D=C-(X'X)^{-1}X'$ we have: $$\hat{\gamma}=(X'X)^{-1}X'y + Dy.$$  Then the first few lines of the proof on Wikipedia can be written as (conditioning on $X$ here):

\begin{aligned}E[\hat{\gamma}|X]&=E[Cy|X]\\
&=E\left[\left((X'X)^{-1}X'+D\right)(X\beta +\varepsilon )|X\right]\\
&=\left((X'X)^{-1}X'+D\right)X\beta +\left((X'X)^{-1}X'+D\right)\operatorname {E} [\varepsilon |X ].\end{aligned}
However, the last line only works if $E[D\varepsilon|X]=DE[\varepsilon|X]$. **Where was this assumed in the Gauss-Markov Theorem?**

Again, the situation is not unique to the Wikipedia proof, but is present in some form or another in every proof I have seen.

I am looking for clarification on what estimators we are actually comparing the OLS estimator to in the Gauss Markov Theorem.

Comment: Why would you assume that $C$ is not $X$-measurable?

Comment: @d.k.o. Why not? My post is not about the practicality of assuming $C$ is $X-$measurable, it is about the fact that the statement of the Gauss-Markov Theorem seems to say nothing about $X-$measurability of $C$, and if $C$ is not required to be $X-$measurable, then it seems to me the typical strategy for proving the result (e.g. the Wikipedia proof) fails.

Comment: You only observe $Y$ and $X$. So any estimator (linear or not) is a function of $Y$ and $X$. In particular, a linear estimator is a linear function of $Y$, i.e., $CY+a$.

Comment: @d.k.o. The fact that "you only observe $Y$ and $X$" is not stated in any way in the GM Theorem. Suppose I generate $Z =f(X,V)$ where $V$ is a random vector I simulate from a computer. I then use my new matrix $Z$ to construct the matrix $C$. Then $C$ need not be $X$-measurable ($V$ may not even be on the same probability space as $X$). What is to prevent me from doing this under the assumptions of the GM theorem?